# Using CASE with Else in SQL view

Tags: sql-server, if-statement, subquery, case, calculated-columns

I have a view in which I have to figure out correct value of FERPA column using CASE statement. The value should be 'Y' or 'N' depending on AddressType.  However, we have some AddressTypes values with which our customer do not agree so they want me to using following logic:

If AddressType = permanent then use value from CMN_PersonsFERPA table (this table was recently created) and choose IsPermAddressFerpa flag. 
If AddressType = local then use value from cmn_personsFERPA table and choose IsLocalAddressFerpa flag.

If AddressType = outside source or international, etc.  Then check to see if the user has value = 'Y' in any columns that are in CMN_PersonsFERPA table (look at the view below).

The issue is that I can easily do what the customer is asking if I can use @CMN_PersonsID parameter.  However, these view is already being used by many applications so I need to figure out a way to do it without using @CMN_PersonsID parameter.  How can I do this?

```
SELECT 

Per.CMN_PersonsID, Per.FullName as Name,
IsFERPA = 
CASE PAL.AddressType
        WHEN 'Permanent' THEN PerFerpa.IsPermAddressFerpa
        WHEN 'Local' THEN PerFerpa.IsLocalAddressFerpa                        
    ELSE
CASE WHEN (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.CMN_PersonsFerpa PerFerpa WHERE cmn_personsid = @CMN_PersonsID AND 
        (IsPermAddressFerpa = 'Y' or    
        IsAcctHoldAddressFerpa = 'Y' or         
        IsBillingAddressFerpa = 'Y' or   
        IsBillingAddress2Ferpa = 'Y' or             
        IsCSSProfAddressFerpa = 'Y' or   
        IsDiplomaAddressFerpa = 'Y' or   
        IsLocalAddressFerpa = 'Y' or     
        IsOutsideSrcAddressFerpa = 'Y' or   
        IsTaxInfoAddressFerpa = 'Y' or   
        IsTempAddressFerpa = 'Y' or   
        IsUnivHousingAddressFerpa = 'Y' or   
        IsWorkAddressFerpa = 'Y')) = 1
    THEN 'Y'
    ELSE 'N'
END
end 
 FROM   CMN_Persons Per WITH (NOLOCK) 
 Inner Join  CMB_Accounts Acc WITH (NOLOCK) ON (Per.CMN_PersonsID = Acc.EntityID AND Acc.EntityType = 'P') 
 inner join CMN_PersonsFerpa PerFerpa WITH (NOLOCK) ON ( PerFerpa.CMN_PersonsID = Acc.EntityID AND Acc.EntityType = 'P' )
 left outer Join CMN_PersonsAddressesLinks PAL WITH (NOLOCK) ON (Per.CMN_PersonsID = PAL.CMN_PersonsID AND PAL.ispreferred = 'Y')
 left outer join CMN_Addresses Addr WITH (NOLOCK) on (PAL.CMN_AddressesID = Addr.CMN_AddressesID)
```

Comment: Note:  there is 1 to 1 relationship between CMN_Persons and Cmn_PersonsFerpa.

Comment: Why, can't you just replace `@CMN_PersonsID` with `Per.CMN_PersonsID`?

Comment: I guess I was thinking way too hard about this issue and completely forgot I could use per.cmn_personsID instead of @cmn_personsID!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by replacing @cmn_personsID with PAL.Cmn_personsID.